# Visual Basic display all output from query in multiple labels using FOR...NEXT Loop

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Currently, my code is like this:

```
Private Sub btnAlaCarte_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAlaCarte.Click
        Dim item(2) As String
        Dim description(2) As String
        Dim price(2) As String
        conn.Open()
        sql = "SELECT name, description, price FROM Food WHERE id LIKE 'F%';"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            For count = 1 To 3 Step 1
                dr.Read()
                lklblItem1.Text = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("name"))
                lblDescription.Text = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("description"))
                lblPrice.Text = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("price"))
            Next
        End If
        dr.Close()
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

I have 3 set of label in my design. Each of the set consist of 1 linklabelItem, 1 labelDescription and 1 labelPrice.  All of them will display different output from database. I manage to extract all of the data that i want. But now the problem is the FOR....NEXT loop only display the output at the first set.

Is there any possibility for me to use For....NEXT Loop to achieve my concept?

Hopes my question is clear enough.

Comment: Normally what we do is bind the query results to some kind of data control, like a gridview, formview, or flowlayoutpanel. But if you want to do things the hard way, that's still possible. The problem right now is there's only one set of labels shown in this code. What are the others? We don't have information yet in the question to help you.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the other set will not display anything

Comment: every step of the loop you're setting lbl.Text on the same controls instead of new ones

Comment: What other set? You tell us they exist, but we only see the one set of anything to display to in the sample code.

Comment: I just create them in design page but i didnt code them inside it, I think this is the place that lead to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `DataGridView` control will do the job without explicit `For .. Next` loop.

```vb
' Create a class to represent a food item
Public Class AlaCarteItem
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property Price As Decimal
End Class

' Extract loading data into dedicated function with properly disposed sql connection
Private Function GetAlaCarte() As List(Of AlaCarteItem)
    Dim query As String = "SELECT name, description, price FROM Food WHERE id LIKE 'F%';"

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using command As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
            connection.Open()
            Dim items = new List(Of AlaCarteItem)()

            Using reader AS SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read()
                    Dim item As New AlaCarteItem With
                    {
                        .Name = reader.GetString(0),
                        .Description = reader.GetString(1),
                        .Price = reader.GetDecimal(2),
                    }

                    items.Add(item)
                End While
            End Using

            Return items
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Add DataGridView control to the form

```
Private btnAlaCarte_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAlaCarte.Click
    Me.DataGridView.DataSource = GetAlaCarte()

    ' Make all columns read only
    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn in Me.DataGridView.Columns
       column.ReadOnly = True
    End With
End Sub
```

You can create DataGridView with predefined columns and make them readonly in design time, then you don't need to do this in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Start in the form designer.
In the toolbox drag a `BindingNavigator` to the form. Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/bindingnavigator-control-overview-windows-forms

Remove the buttons that you will not use by right clicking on the buttons and selecting delete. You will end up with a strip that looks like this.

[image]

Then, in the code

1. Fill a `DataTable`
2. Create a `BindingSource`
3. Set the `DataSource` of the `BindingSource` to the `DataTable`
4. Finally set the `BindingSource` property of the `BindingNavigator` control to the the `BindingSource`.

Next your will add  `DataBindings` to each of your controls.
The `.Add` method takes 3 parameters in this overload. 
    1.The property to bind to, in this case we are binding the `Text` property
    2. The `BindingSource` (`bindSrc`)
    3. The member of the `DataTable` to bind to.
Note: The name of my `Form` is `BindingNavigator`

```
Private Sub BindingNavigator_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt = LoadData()
    Dim bindSrc As New BindingSource
    bindSrc.DataSource = dt
    BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bindSrc
    lblItem.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", bindSrc, "name"))
    lblDescription.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", bindSrc, "description"))
    lblPrice.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", bindSrc, "price"))
End Sub

Private Function LoadData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT name, description, price FROM Food WHERE id LIKE 'F%';", conn)
        conn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

You will then be able to move through the records with the BindingNavigator toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing your labels' texts in each iteration. I recommend to use a datagrid instead. However, if you want to use labels anyway, update your loop as this:

```
lklblItem1.Text += vbNewLine + dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("name"))
                lblDescription.Text += vbNewLine + dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("description"))
                lblPrice.Text += vbNewLine + dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("price"))
```

Comment: does the new line need to declare or import anything? As i get declaration require for the `NewLine`

Comment: No no. Sory I made a mistake. Please type vbNewLine instead. I edited my answer.